# MS SQL - Display Last Name & First name without changing record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that uses two tables. One is Contact, the other is Email. Contact has the following columns: ContactId, FirstName, LastName. Email has the following columns: EmailId, ContactId, EmailAddress.

I have this query that runs a basic duplicate check. It will return a numeric value and an Email (i.e., 2 - abc@yahoo.com = 2 contacts have the email abc@yahoo.com). I'm trying to get it to display the First Name and Last Name associated with the email, but when I do so, it changes the amount of data being produced. This is likely because it's grabbing Emails that have First and Last Names attached to them as well.

Here's the query; when I try to input SELECT CONTACT.LASTNAME and CONTACT. FIRSTNAME, as well as a GROUP BY, it will change the amount of data outputed; more columns are created (expected), but there are also more rows and the data is actually less relevant (more nulls are returned). What's causing this, and how can I fix it?

```
SELECT COUNT(CONTACT.CONTACTID) AS [DUPLICATECOUNT], EMAIL.ADDRESS AS [EMAILADDRESS]
FROM CONTACT
INNER JOIN EMAIL on EMAIL.ContactID = CONTACT.ContactId
GROUP BY EMAIL.ADDRESS
HAVING COUNT (CONTACT.ContactID) > 1
ORDER BY [DUPLICATECOUNT] DESC
```

Comment: define "changes the amount of data being produced": more columns (guaranteed)? more rows (very unlikely)? if the former, what else did you expect? do you want them to show as a single column (think 'cell') instead?

Comment: More columns, less rows
EDIT: Actually more rows, but technically less data (more nulls are displayed)

Comment: What are your expected results?  As you figured out, grouping by those 2 fields will affect the counts if the names are different -- that will add more results.  Are you wanting to combine the names into a single column?

Comment: "do you want them to show as a single column (think 'cell') instead?" then just research basic _string concatenation_.

Comment: The expected results are to have the four columns: The dupe count, the address that is duped, and the first name/last names associated with the email address. However based on how I'm doing the query - it's just changing the results to only filter on duplicates that have a first name + last names. If the names can be combined into a single column, this could work too, just something I have not tried.

Comment: Sql Server doesn't support `group_concat` -- but that's what you should look up on SO (lots of examples out there).  You can achieve the same with `stuff` and `for xml`.

Comment: @sgeddes it doesn't support `LISTAGG()` also :)

Answer (score 0):

If your MS SQL Server is 2008 or newer then you can use window function to find duplicates. Sample query looks like this.

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname, e.emailaddress,
       count(c.contactid) over(partition by e.emailaddress order by e.emailaddress) cnt
from contact c
     inner join email e on c.contactid = e.contactid 
order by cnt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, you are  trying to get it to display the First Name and Last Name associated with the email:

```
select FirstName, LastName
FROM CONTACT C WITH (NOLOCK), EMAIL E WITH (NOLOCK) 
where C.ContactID = E.ContactId
AND EmailAddress='emailaddress@yahoo.com'
```